# DAX - hard mode - changing total sum of measure

Tags: algorithm, azure, powerbi, dax

I'm new to Power BI & Dax, and I'm struggling with one Dax Formula, I've been trying for couple of days already :/

```
Product SKU coming from --- > DIM table Product LCBO

9L cs & Fin COGS per 9L BL coming from --->  Fact promotion table
```

relationship between tables :
[image]

[image]

As an example :

| Product SKU | 9L cs | Fin COGS per 9L BL | COGS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sku1 | 1000 | 22.5 | 1000*22.5=22500 |
| sku2 | 200 | 23.1 | 200*23.1=59=4620 |
| sku3 | 33 | 19 | 33*19=627 |
| sku4 | 5000 |  |  |
| sku5 |  | 90 |  |
| sku6 |  |  |  |
| TOTAL | 6233 | 38.65 | 240,905.45 |
| **Expected TOTAL** | 6233 | 38.65 | **22500+4620+627=27,747** |

Then I got the formula right. BUT ! once I remove the column Product SKU, I got the result below which is not correct :

Yeah In fact, once I removed the SKU product dimensions, the calculation should go back to normal, Why I still have the sum of each product value ?

| 9L cs | Fin COGS per 9L BL | COGS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6233 | 38.65 | 22500+4620+627=27,747 |
| **expected total** |  | **6233*38.65 = 240,905.45** |

Initial formula for COGS was :

```
cogs = [Fin COGS per 9L BL] *[9L Cs]
```

I tried :

## Formula 1

```
cogs = SUMX(VALUES('Facts Promotion'[Cases 9L]),[Fin COGS per 9L BL]*[9L Cs])
```

This one works when I removed the product column, but doens't work when I use product column

## Formula 2

```
cogs = SUMX('Product LCBO',[Fin COGS per 9L BL] *[9L Cs])
```

this one works is the opposite it works when I use product but doesn't when I remove product column

Thanks in advance for people that will try to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't your formula, the problem is you're expectations are wrong.

It's not clear from your post, but the two examples are from two separate measures.  It took me a second, but it appears in your examples that the *9L cs* and *Fin COGS per 9L BL* columns are actually measures themselves.  So in your first example the only dimension filtering your results is the *product sku* and in the second no filter is being applied.

In your first example you expect the total to be the **sum of the product for each row**, while in the second example you expect the total to be the **product of the sum for each column**.  You can't easily have it both ways.

What I recommend is you be clear on what you're after.

You can do a conditional expression that checks if Product SKU is filtered to produce the result you want.

```
cogs = IF(
    ISCROSSFILTERED('Product LCBO'[Product Sku]), 
    SUMX('Product LCBO',[Fin COGS per 9L BL] *[9L Cs]), 
    SUMX(VALUES('Facts Promotion'[Cases 9L]),[Fin COGS per 9L BL]*[9L Cs])
)
```